# HOWTO: Simulate click OK in WebBrowser alert/messagebox that initiated by a JavaScript? (Delphi)

Tags: javascript, delphi, click, browser, alert

I have an app with a WebBrowser inside:

when I POST my webpage i have javascript popup alert/messagebox comes on where I need to click OK. Here is my javascript that creates the alert:

```
    function delete(){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this ?')){
            document.forms.item.action = "edit.asp?action=delete";
            document.forms.item.submit();
        }

    }
```

I was searching for a while but could not yet find any working solution...

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Use a tool like Winspector to identify the class or title of the window that the alert appears in. Then create a timer on your form to watch for that window appearing, and then use SendMessage to send it a mousedown or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage](http://www.bsalsa.com/ewb_on_show_mess.html) and show your own dialog, or just return S_OK.

Note:The link is broken. Here the code for the solution:

```
      IDocHostShowUI = interface(IUnknown)
        ['{c4d244b0-d43e-11cf-893b-00aa00bdce1a}']
        function ShowMessage(hwnd: THandle; lpstrText: POleStr; lpstrCaption: POleStr;
          dwType: longint; lpstrHelpFile: POleStr; dwHelpContext: longint;
          var plResult: LRESULT): HRESULT; stdcall;
      end;

      TShowMessageEvent = function(Sender: TObject; HWND: THandle;
        lpstrText: POleStr; lpstrCaption: POleStr; dwType: Longint; lpstrHelpFile: POleStr;
        dwHelpContext: Longint; var plResult: LRESULT): HRESULT of object;

      TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser, IDocHostShowUI)
        private
          fOnShowMessage: TShowMessageEvent;
        protected
          function ShowMessage(HWND: THandle; lpstrText: POleStr; lpstrCaption: POleStr;
            dwType: Longint; lpstrHelpFile: POleStr; dwHelpContext: Longint;
            var plResult: LRESULT): HRESULT; stdcall;
        published
          property OnShowMessage: TShowMessageEvent read fOnShowMessage write
            fOnShowMessage;
      end;

function TWebBrowser.ShowMessage(HWND: THandle; lpstrText, lpstrCaption: POleStr;
  dwType: Integer; lpstrHelpFile: POleStr; dwHelpContext: Integer;
  var plResult: LRESULT): HRESULT;
begin
  if Assigned(fOnShowMessage) then
    Result := fOnShowMessage(Self, HWND, lpstrText, lpStrCaption, dwType,
      lpStrHelpFile, dwHelpContext, plResult)
  else
  Result:= S_OK;
end;
```

Comment: That is actually the best solution for my problem:
`function CommandTarget_Exec(CmdGroup: PGUID; nCmdID, nCmdexecopt: DWORD; const vaIn: OleVariant; var vaOut: OleVariant): HRESULT; 

begin
  if nCmdID = OLECMDID_SHOWMESSAGE then
  begin

   Result:=S_OK;
   vaOut:=true;
   exit;
  end;
end;'

Answer (score 1):

If this is for very restricted, internal, usage, you can do a dirty

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  TargetCaption = 'Meddelande från webbsida';
var
  S: string;
  len: integer;
begin
  SetLength(S, 127);
  len := GetWindowText(Application.ActiveFormHandle, PChar(S), 127);
  if len = 0 then Exit;
  SetLength(S, len);
  if S = TargetCaption then
    SendMessage(Application.ActiveFormHandle, WM_COMMAND, ID_OK, 0);
end;
```

where `TargetCaption` is the known caption of the `TWebBrowser` popup, confirm, or prompt dialogs. This may vary between OS versions and language versions, so this approach is only acceptable in a very restricted, in-house application, where it is OK to 'update' the application with every new Windows SP...

By the way, "Meddelande från webbsida" is Swedish for "Message from web page".

Comment: Tack så mycket! Great answer, I am just testing your solution right now.

Comment: Worked fine! Good luck for Svenska in the handball final! :) We just lost to you yesterday.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the text from the website and press NO on a Yes/No dialog from IE? Tack!

Comment: ID_NO and ID_YES got it :)

Answer (score -2):

Buttons on `alert()` `confirm()` and `prompt()` boxes are not scriptable. Use a HTML/CSS modal dialog instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: -1 Actually, you can override alert() and confirm() boxes with `IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage`